# Division in code snippet

Tags: c, image-processing

I'm having big problems understanding what the `(imageptt->h / 4) + (i / 2)` does in:

```
 for(int i= 0; i < imageptt->h; i++)
 {
     for(int j = 0; j < imageptt->w; j++)
     { 
        pixels[i][j] = old[(imageptt->h / 4) + (i / 2)]
                                     [(imageptt->w  / 4) + (j / 2)];
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's a linear mapping of coordinates where the pixels are downscaled by a factor of two and shifted by a quarter of the total size.

Answer (score 0):

What this code appears to do is to set `new_pixels` to the central quarter of `old_pixels`, scaled up to be the same size.

For example, if `old_pixels` is:

```
ABCDEFGH
IHJKLMNO
PQRSTUVW
XYZabcde
fghijklm
nopqrstu
vwxyz012
3456789*
```

Then `new_pixels` will be set to

```
RRSSTTUU
RRSSTTUU
ZZaabbcc
ZZaabbcc
hhiijjkk
hhiijjkk
ppqqrrss
ppqqrrss
```

(Assuming that there is an outer loop over the rows of the image).

Adding `(image_ptr->height / 4)` and `(image_ptr->width / 4)` to the indices starts reading from an offset 1/4 of the way vertically and horizontally into `old_pixels`. Dividing `(i / 2)` and `(j / 2)` scales the image up by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is a bit strange as it defaults on the cases where i and j are not even - it could be intentional but does look like a bug.
It looks like new pixels is trying to get the central quarter of old pixels, but because of the odd indices, every pixel will be sampled twice

if the old pixels were:

```
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
A A B B C C D D
```

the new pixels will be

```
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
B B B B C C C C
```